# Fill form from Java Android and send Request

Tags: java, android, http, lua

I'm trying to fill form from Java program for Android and send request to the server. First I tried to use a Selenium for Android, but I failed to start it, then I found to many examples  about, how to use HttpPost etc.., but the action of the form is:

form name="mainform" method="POST" action="/system/boxuser_edit.lua"

So I found the following code, and I tried to many possible combination, but without success

```
    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String paramUsername = params[0];
            String paramPassword = params[1];

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(),100000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 100000);
    String SID = "xxxxxxxxx";
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://fritz.box/system/boxuser_edit.lua?sid="+SID+"=new");

            BasicNameValuePair emailBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("user", paramUsername);

            BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("password", paramPassword);

            // We add the content that we want to pass with the POST request to as name-value pairs
            //Now we put those sending details to an ArrayList with type safe of NameValuePair
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
            nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePair);

            try {
                // UrlEncodedFormEntity is an entity composed of a list of url-encoded pairs. 
                //This is typically useful while sending an HTTP POST request. 
                UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);

                // setEntity() hands the entity (here it is urlEncodedFormEntity) to the request.
                httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

                try {
                    // HttpResponse is an interface just like HttpPost.
                    //Therefore we can't initialize them
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    // According to the JAVA API, InputStream constructor do nothing. 
                    //So we can't initialize InputStream although it is not an interface
                    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                    while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                    }

                    return stringBuilder.toString();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                    System.out.println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);
                    cpe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                System.out.println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :" + uee);
                uee.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }           
    }
    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(givenUsername, givenPassword);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have just bunch of questions before we discuss your code because what you did here seems to be correct.

First of all did you request a permission to access network in the manifest file?
if it's not this is how you do it:

add this line of code to your androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But before that you have to check that the link you are passing to the HttpPost Object is working, you can use a web browser to test it, because i just did that right now and it seems that it doesn't work!!

Comment: Hi, I added the permission, but still doesn't work. The link works, I can open it, and the SID is correct. I dont know where the problem is.